# How to output single character in C with write?

Tags: c, function, unix

Could someone instruct me on ***how*** to print a single letter, for example "b" in C while using only the write function (not printf).

I'm pretty sure it uses

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Could you also tell me how the write properties work? I don't really understand

```
int  write(  int  handle,  void  *buffer,  int  nbyte  );
```

Could some of you guys toss in a few C beginner tips as well?

I am using UNIX.

Comment: The `buffer` would be the address of the `char myb ='b'` and the `nbyte` size would be 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have found your function, all you need now is to pass it proper parameters:

```
int handle = open("myfile.bin", O_WRONLY);
//... You need to check the result here
int count = write(handle, "b", 1); // Pass a single character
if (count == 1) {
    printf("Success!");
}
```

> I did indeed want to use stdout. How do I write a version to display the whole alphabet?

You could use a pre-defined constant for stdout. It is called `STDOUT_FILENO`.

If you would like to write out the whole alphabet, you could do it like this:

```
for (char c = 'A' ; c <= 'Z' ; c++) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/OYuo9m)

Comment: no doubt, but just because the mention of `printf()`, i thought OP wanted to print to stdout, not to file. In that case, it would have been `fprintf()`. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Now that you have mentioned it, I am not sure if OP really wants to write to stdout or not.

Comment: I did indeed want to use stdout. The answer above worked for me while this one did not, however. 
Question - how would I do the write version to display the whole alphabet? I know char c and such would have to do with it. Also, what's "c++;" used for in this and most scenarios?

Comment: Cool! What is the c++ part used for? I can't find it anywhere. 
Also, any way to do it without **for** and maybe replaced by a **while**?

Comment: @ButterMyBitter This is an increment operation on the character. Rewriting a `for` loop as a `while` loop is a good exercise that is purely mechanical. It's good to try to do independently.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) of `write()`, which says,

> `ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);`
>
> #### Description
>
> `write()` writes up to `count` bytes from the buffer pointed `buf` to the file referred to by the file descriptor `fd`.

As per your requirement, you need to pass an address of a buffer containing `b` to print to standard output.

Let's see some code along with, shall we?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char  b = 'b';
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &b, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Let me explain. Here, the `STDOUT_FILENO` is the file descriptior for standard output as defined in `unistd.h`, `&b` is the address of the *buffer* containing `'b'` and the number of bytes is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Also valid is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char  b[1] = {'b'};
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, b, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    char  b[1] = "b";
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, b, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `write(STDOUT_FILENO, (char[]){'b'}, 1);`

Comment: @0___________  he wanted it in a variable :P